# create callback url in asp.net core api

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core-webapi

I try to use Identity in asp.net core API, everything works fine except I couldn't find a way to create call back url for email confirmation.
I searched a lot, but no one implemented Identity with email confirmation in ASP.NET core API.

Here's my `RegisterUser` code:

```
var user = new ApplicationUser
        {
            Name = model.Name,
            Email = model.Email,
            UserName = model.Email
        };

var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

if (result.Succeeded)
{
    await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "User");

    var token = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
    var callbackurl = Url.RouteUrl("ConfirmEmail", new { userId = user.Id, token = token }, protocol: Request.Scheme);
    var message = new Message(
              new string[] { model.Email },
              Messages.Email_Confirmation,
               Messages.Email_CreateUser_Body + "<a href=\"" + callbackurl + "\">link</a>"
            );

    _emailSender.SendEmail(message);

    return Ok();
}
```

The above code 'callbackurl' return null. I tried other methods for creating url but it won't work.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: [Have you try to use `Url.Page` ?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/accconfirm?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#disable-default-account-verification-when-accountregisterconfirmation-has-been-scaffolded)

Comment: thanks for your reply.I used Url.page and I got this error.The relative page path 'ConfirmEmail' can only be used while executing a Razor Page. I want to use in API controller

Comment: The effect of Url.page and Url.RouteUrl should be similar, this should not be the key to this problem, please use the previous Url.RouteUrl, thank you~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the root cause, it is because you are missing routing configuration.

*In .net6, program.cs*

```
...
app.MapControllers();

// add this code
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "ConfirmEmail",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

This is just my test code, I reproduce the issue in my local, and I faced the issue, and after add `app.MapControllerRoute`, it works.

Comment: I'm extremely grateful!